# How do I check if a sound is playing in the background?

Tags: vb.net, audio, background

I'm using `My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Sound1, AudioPlayMode.Background)`
to play my sound, but I need to check if it's already playing before executing this code because otherwise it just keeps looping to the start of the audio file, is there any way to do this in vb.net?

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible without external library.
You can use a OpenSource DLL like NAudio or LibZPlay to play and give all control over the player.
It's simple and very efficient.

http://naudio.codeplex.com

http://libzplay.sourceforge.net/

Att.

Anderson